# Java compilation error with varargs

Tags: java, compilation, variadic-functions

I created a library with the following method :

```
protected static int foo(String strParam, Object... params)
```

I link this library to my application and I call the method :

```
foo("a","b")
```

but it does not compile, I get the following error message : 
*actual argument String cannot be converted to Object[] by method invocation conversion.*

any idea ?

Comment: What version of Java are you calling it from?

Answer (score 3):

Works for me:

```
public class XXX extends Lib {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo("a", "b");
    }
}

class Lib{
    protected static int foo(String str, Object... args) {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

So:

- What JDK version are you using?
- What source/class version of Java are you using? Anything below "5" is useless.
- Are there other methods called `foo` somewhere (i.e. overloaded methods)?
- Are you sure you don't "link" (whatever that means to you) against an old version of your code?

Comment: What JDK version are you using? -> JDK 1.5_22

Comment: What source/class version of Java are you using? Anything below "5" is useless. -> I compile with -target 1.5 and source 1.5

Comment: Are there other methods called foo somewhere (i.e. overloaded methods)? -> NO

Comment: I works for me if I call the foo method directly in the library code but it fails if I call the foo method from another program

Answer (score 0):

The method is `protected`.  Is the call occurring in a class in the same package, or in a subclass?  If not, the caller cannot see this definition of `foo`.  I don't see why it would result in that particular error though.  This might be evidence that the compiler is trying to match this up with a different method signature.

Is your call really just `foo( ... )`?  I would expect to see the name of the containing class there, since it is a static method -- i.e. `LibraryClass.foo( ... )`.  If you are not qualifying the method name, then it should be looking in the local class scope for a matching declaration.